# Duplicate log entries log4j

Tags: java, spring-mvc, log4j

I am getting duplicate entries in my log file.
Have attached my log4j.properties below.

**log4j.properties:**

```
###############################################################################
# log4j Configuration file: Defines following loggers
# SL    -   Standard root Logger
# EL    -   Error Logger with the threshold level explicitly set to ERROR
# DL    -   Data base logger - to log db queries separately
# BL    -   Batch logger
###############################################################################

log4j.rootLogger=TRACE,SL,EL
log4j.rootLogger.additivity=false

#Standard Log
log4j.appender.SL=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SL.File=${log.file}/log.log
log4j.appender.SL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SL.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%X{sessionId}:%X{hostId}:%X{userId}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

#Error Log
log4j.appender.EL=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.EL.File=${log.file}/error.log
log4j.appender.EL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.EL.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.EL.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%X{sessionId}:%X{hostId}:%X{userId}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

# Database Log
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG,DL

log4j.appender.DL=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DL.File=${log.file}/db.log
log4j.appender.DL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DL.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%X{sessionId}:%X{hostId}:%X{userId}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

#Forecast Log
log4j.appender.MAPS_FC=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MAPS_FC.File=${log.file}/forecast.log
log4j.appender.MAPS_FC.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MAPS_FC.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%X{sessionId}:%X{hostId}:%X{userId}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

#Logger configuration
log4j.logger.com.singaporeair.maps=TRACE,SL,EL
log4j.logger.com.singaporeair.maps.app.service.impl.gantt=DEBUG,MAPS_FC
log4j.logger.com.singaporeair.maps.app.dao.impl.gantt=DEBUG,MAPS_FC
```

Getting dulicate entries in *log.log* file configured above.

**Log extract:**

```
[ INFO] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9 19:04:00:800] [::] (AppProfiler.java:doProfile:69) Processing Time(ms): BaseDAOImpl: getBatchDetails: 63
[ INFO] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9 19:04:00:800] [::] (AppProfiler.java:doProfile:69) Processing Time(ms): BaseDAOImpl: getBatchDetails: 63
[ INFO] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9 19:04:00:800] [::] (AppProfiler.java:doProfile:71) BaseDAOImpl: getBatchDetails: OUT
[ INFO] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9 19:04:00:800] [::] (AppProfiler.java:doProfile:71) BaseDAOImpl: getBatchDetails: OUT
```

Pls help

Comment: Is it related to logger additivity?

Comment: no.. i just tried making it false. But still i am getting duplicates..

Comment: YOu mean in root? It is not inherited, you need to do it for each child logger

Comment: can u please explain in details? tnx!!

Comment: At least remove / replace the name of the company you do this for from the code you post.

Comment: Yeah.. just noticed. Will do it for future posts..

Comment: Set Additivitity to false for every logger you have declared in the config file

Answer (score 18):

If you turn off additivity, the loggers that are children of the parents won't cause double logging. For instance:

```
#Logger configuration
log4j.logger.com.singaporeair.maps=TRACE,SL,EL
log4j.additivity.com.singaporeair.maps=false

log4j.logger.com.singaporeair.maps.app.service.impl.gantt=DEBUG,MAPS_FC
log4j.additivity.com.singaporeair.maps.app.service.impl.gantt=false

log4j.logger.com.singaporeair.maps.app.dao.impl.gantt=DEBUG,MAPS_FC
log4j.additivity.com.singaporeair.maps.app.dao.impl.gantt=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably would be helpful for those who experience duplicate problem in a multithread application (couldn't find the answer in google):

This happens when one thread is done and another thread open logger to the same log file which the first thread used to write.

`.removeAllAppenders()` before I added a new appender helped to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`com.singaporeair.maps` is a superset of `com.singaporeair.maps.app.service.impl.gantt` and `com.singaporeair.maps.app.dao.impl.gantt`

Everything that matches `com.singaporeair.maps.app.dao.impl.gantt` will also match `com.singaporeair.maps` which will result in 2 log entties.

Guess 1: You need to turn off appender inheritance.  It appears that this is wrong.

Guess 2: The root logger and the com.singaporeair.maps are both logging to the SL and EL appenders.  This is just a guess, but try changing this:

```
log4j.logger.com.singaporeair.maps=TRACE,SL,EL
```

to this:

```
log4j.logger.com.singaporeair.maps=TRACE
```

Comment: removing the logger names (in this case SL/EL) worked for me. i didn't know that its ok to remove them. thanks!