# duplicate log entries (Log4j)

Tags: java, log4j

Am getting dupliate log entries when using the below log4j properties.

```
log4j.rootLogger.additivity=false
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE

#Standard Log
log4j.appender.SL=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SL.File=${log.file}/log.log
log4j.appender.SL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SL.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%X{sessionId}:%X{hostId}:%X{userId}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

#Error Log
log4j.appender.EL=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.EL.File=${log.file}/error.log
log4j.appender.EL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.EL.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.EL.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%X{sessionId}:%X{hostId}:%X{userId}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

# Database Log
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG,DL

log4j.appender.DL=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DL.File=${log.file}/db.log
log4j.appender.DL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DL.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%X{sessionId}:%X{hostId}:%X{userId}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

#Logger configuration
log4j.logger.com.singaporeair.maps=TRACE
```

Could not find out the cause of the duplicates.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Post a sample of your log output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate log entries log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489929/duplicate-log-entries-log4j)

Answer (score 0):

This properties file should cause you to have NO logging. The rootlogger has a no appenders defined. This makes me think you are actually using a different configuration that posted here.