# Run 2 SpringApplication simultaneously in same JVM?

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot

I'm running some code as 2 separate configurations as follows:

```
        SpringApplication north = new SpringApplication(MyApp.class);
        north.setAdditionalProfiles("north");
        north.run();

        SpringApplication south = new SpringApplication(MyApp.class);
        south.setAdditionalProfiles("south");
        south.run()
```

This works fine. However, as soon as I try to run them simultaneously on a `ForkJoinPool`, as two separate tasks, the logging goes haywire (same log messages appear 2-3 times or more for each thread).

I tried setting `org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem=none` but it had no effect.

Is there a documented way to run two SpringBoot configurations simultaneously in the same JVM?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) of the logging going haywire?

Comment: I was not able to distill an MCVE but you can see examples in some of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489929/duplicate-log-entries-log4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed by moving the multi-threaded part of the application out of `CommandLineRunner::run` / `SpringApplication::run` to a Bean. Relegating `SpringApplication::run` to just perform initialization, using the returned `ConfigurableApplicationContext` to resolve and invoke the Bean based process.